# Azure Web App For Containers - Correct Port Setup and Logging Issue

Tags: azure, docker, shiny, docker-compose, azure-webapps

I have an rshiny server setup in a docker container, and am trying to deploy this as an azure multi-container web app with some other services. I've already succeeded in deploying it in the single-container setting, for which I set the WEBSITES_PORT app setting to be 3838.

In my attempt to move to the multi-container situation, using the following docker-compose script:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  shiny-app:
    image: my-shiny-image
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:3838"
```

My understanding is that the 80-3838 mapping is what "informs" azure of what the website port is? This does not work when deployed, and I cannot retrieve any docker logs. I get the error message "Error retrieving logs". If I run the

```
az webapp log tail
```

command, it just hangs and then fails.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can try to change the ports as "3838:80".

Comment: Adding to Charles comments- In your app, please use the PORT environment variable as the main web server’s listening port, instead of using a hardcoded port number. The PORT environment variable is automatically set by App Service platform at startup time.